# Where can I ask question about offshore USA medical school or colleges?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, moderation

I would like to know which part of stackexchange is most suitable for posing a question about credibility of offshore medical schools, their accreditation and acceptance in USA and if it is easier to get in residence program via them faster and easier in contrast to regular outside of USA graduate procedure?  DO YOU think maybe expat forum or medical forum can be suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Medical school is a form of postgraduate education that is certainly within scope of this site.  Asking for evaluation of particular schools would not be, nor would asking something highly opinion-based like "which is better?" or highly personal like "which is easier for me to get into?"  Accreditation and acceptance in the USA would be on topic.

Note that your questions might not be answered as quickly as PhD-centric questions, but that should be no barrier to asking them.

Comment: So concretely, accreditations of medical USA offshore schools, if someone had experience with these kind of institutions and how they menage to recognize their studies back in USA. What is law and regulation regarding off shore departments in general? This would be my question, do you think it is opinion based?

Comment: "What is law and regulation regarding off shore departments in general?" would be too broad, since it's not clear which of the *many* possible issues you're asking about..  "Are there significant barriers to getting offshore medical degrees recognized in the US?" would probably be fine.

Comment: thank you! "Are there significant barriers to getting offshore medical degrees recognized in the US and if there are not, is it beneficial for residency application? Is this ok question? I will than further explain  about why students decide to apply for off shore departments and how they validate their diplomas for residency entrance more quickly in contrast to foreign diplomas...blabla...in global, this can be acceptable question and explanation of question?

Comment: @SSimon I would recommending one question at a time, rather than making compound questions.  Sometimes, however, compound questions are OK.